# Emails sent via application on RDS server stuck in outbox - Outlook

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, windows-server-2012-r2

We currently generate and process documents via an application hosted on a RDS server. Users access the application via remote desktop applications and do not login to there desktop on the server.

Some users email large amounts once or twice a week (~200-300) in a batch, which defaults to Outlook as the sender, and outlook runs in the background as the user does not utilise outlook on the server other than sending emails from the application.

We are encountering an issue where all emails become stuck in the outbox, until you login to the users server profile, open outlook, and "send all" emails from the outbox. This has never been the case before and only recently over the past few months become an ongoing issue.

I have tried, with no success;

1. Change the outlook profile to store emails locally, instead of online. (This does not work, it causes an error which i cannot recall off the top of my head)
2. Leaving outlook open on the users server profile. This also does not seem to be consistent and the user will show two seperate logins under task manager. (One for remote apps, one for server profile)

Office is up to date, i'm unsure where to look from here. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if the thread below is helpful to you.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/22d06ecb-ff51-45f9-a4b1-1de72c55439b/outlook-2013-emails-stuck-in-outbox?forum=officeitpro